# Prestashop Overriding AdminProductsController to add a field to Product Editor

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, prestashop, overriding

I've added another summary to try and concisely convey exactly what I want to do. **In the catalog page for a product, when you edit the page I want to add an on/off switch to the information tab which will enable the display of my custom tab (which is hooking properly) but I'm not 100% certain of what I need to override where to add this button in.**

So as above I'm trying to edit the product information page to add a field which will activate some other product customization.

A snapshot for the admin panel that I'm trying to override:

[image: A snapshot for the admin panel that I'm trying to override]

I already have code which adds a tab to this page inside my module.

```
    public function hookDisplayAdminProductsExtra($params) 
    {
         return $this->display(__FILE__, '/views/product-tab-extension.tpl');
    }
```

This is installing and I can click the myModule tab which loads up product-tab-extension.tpl and displays

```
<h1> hello world </h1>
```

As you can see, I'm hooking in the code that I need :)

[image: As you can see, I'm hooking in the code that I need :)]

However, what I'm currently trying to do, is add a toggle button inside the information page for the product which will turn on my myModule tab inside this catalog controller. So any products that aren't set to be modified by my module won't have the tab showing.

Poking around I've read some articles about requiring the overriding of **AdminProductsController.php** so I've placed the file AdminProductsController.php

```
<?php

class AdminProductsControllerCore extends AdminController
{
}
```

inside modules\myModule\override\controllers\admin

but I'm honestly stuck with where to go from here, I apologize because I'm fried, very tired, very busy and I feel very close to getting it but also still far away.

As far as I can tell I need to track down the .tpl file for this information page (which I think is:)

```
prestashop/adminud/themes/default/template/controllers/products/helpers/form/form.tpl
```

for which I would have a smarty template which extends it and overwrites a block to add in the on/off toggle that I need. Which would call ajax on click to enable my hook for the myModule tab which would then be used to append data to existing products.

However I'm not entirely sure which part of the products.php I'm supposed to override and point to my new .tpl file or if this is even correct.

Once my custom tab is finished I plan to use the form post to take myModule fields from post to append a row to a database table which tracks the product id and the data I'm appending to it.

The end goal is to have code which recognizes my connection and modify the front end to display the linked data along side the product in the shop.

Thanks for your time and I hope I was clear enough!